# MySQL select data across 4 tables (multiple conditions)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Thanks to another user I was finally able to collect some data using this query:

```
SELECT r.form, s.value as email
FROM subrecords s join
     records r
     on s.record = r.id AND r.name = 'question-form'
WHERE s.title = 'email'
GROUP BY s.value, r.form
```

details on the tables involved in the above query are found at [Finding duplicates in MYSQL table where data is in multiple tables (multiple conditions needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812485/finding-duplicates-in-mysql-table-where-data-is-in-multiple-tables-multiple-con/18812587?noredirect=1#18812587)

With the above query I get the list of emails that submitted a specific form.

I would need now to find out which of those email addresses is subscribed to a specific mailing list, Using the "s.value" of the above query which lists email addresses

I first need to find out the subscriber.subid which identifies each unique subscriber and their email address, which is where I would join the result from the query above

> ## table -> subscriber schema
>
> #### subid  | email

Then select from the following table WHERE listid = '33'

> ## table -> listsub schema
>
> #### listid |  subid | subdate | unsubdate | status

Thank you so much everyone for the incredible help!

Comment: did you really get it as i see there should be "where" first then "and"

Comment: @bhawin, I don't think I get your questions, just wanted to clarify the the query in the question does work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way by doing more joins:

```
SELECT r.form, s.value as email,
       (case when max(l.listid is not null) then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as InList33
FROM subrecords s join
     records r
     on s.record = r.id AND r.name = 'question-form' left outer join
     subscriber_schema ss
     on ss.email = s.value left outer join
     listsub l
     on ss.subid = l.subid and
        l.listid = '33'
WHERE s.title = 'email'
GROUP BY s.value, r.form;
```